# What is the difference between objectivity and symmetry?

Tags: group-theory, geometry, algebraic-geometry, tensors

(This question has been posted in [Pyisics Stack Exchange](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/664650/what-is-the-difference-between-objectivity-and-symmetry) without answer).

I encounter this question when reading a paper about continuum mechanics ([Kumar and Parks, 2015, Proc.R.Soc.A](https://royalsocietypublishing.org/doi/full/10.1098/rspa.2014.0567). refer to eq.3.1 and eq.3.3)

Speaking of the **objectivity** of strain energy density ${\psi}$, it reads like,

$$\psi=\hat\psi(F)=\hat\psi(QF)$$

where arbitrary ${Q\in SO_2}$ denotes a rigid-body rotation, and $F$ is the deformation gradient, which is a two-point tensor and should transform like a 1-order tensor.

As for the **symmetry** of ${\psi}$, it reads like,

$$\psi=\bar\psi(E)=\bar\psi(Q^TEQ)\quad \forall Q\in G \, ,$$

where $G$ denotes the material symmetry group, and $E$ is a kind of strain measure, which is a 2-order tensor.

- I am confused by these two equations because it seems to me that both objectivity and symmetry are expressed as rotation-transformation invariance of strain energy density $\psi$. But they don't feel the same, instinctively.
- Could somebody explain the difference between objectivity and symmetry and the corresponding mathematical expression?

Comment: As someone who knows no physics, objectivity sounds like the function $\psi$ is constant on the entire $SO2$-orbit whereas symmetry sounds like the function is just invariant under (special) orthogonal base change.

Comment: These mathematical expressions do not mean a lot when we read a paper and overlook crucial words in the text. When the authors introduce *objectivity* they require indifference of $\hat\psi$ when its argument is expressed in coordinates of the *material frame*. In plain English this means nothing else than $\hat\psi$ is well defined on such coordinates and does not change under *rigid body motions*. In even more plain English this means that every point in the body has a well defined strain energy density regardless how you move the whole body. Very trivial in my opinion.

Comment: ... probably so trivial that the authors felt it should be formalized :) . *Symmetry* of strain energy density is obviously a much more restrictive requirement. Imagine the mass density of a rigid body and how we usually calculate center of mass.